# View TFS changeset details in console

Tags: tfs, console, diff, changeset

I am using TFS and want to view all changes on a changeset that contains changes in several files. Viewing this in the GUI is not efficient as I have to open every single file. What I want to do is to tell TFS on the console to show me all the changes to all files in changeset number 777. Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tf diff <folder> /version:C776~C777 /recursive /format:unified
```

Will give you a diff formatted summary