# Getting the difference between two revisions in TFS

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View TFS changeset details in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006806/view-tfs-changeset-details-in-console)

I need a report of the difference between two revision inside a TFS project.

I'm building a simple patch system, and from an article I read on [#AltDevBlogADay](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/11/12/a-simple-system-to-patch-your-game-content/) describes this system. It says that if you can get the difference between your last patched revision release and the current revision that needs to be distributed for patching, all the files should be very easy to pick up/add/delete.

I tried googling, even the MSDN help on the tf.exe command line calls, but none of them help. I'm using the `tf hist . -r /version:C1~C3` command but it's only producing the name of the committer, the changeset number, and the comment that was left with the changeset, but no details on the individual files, and wheter they were added, created or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***tf diff*** to extract the differences and output them in a file as the following:

> tf diff FabrikamFiber.CallCenter\fabrikamfiber.web\controllers\
>   /version: c7~c26 >c:\Radwan.txt

For more info, I have create a video that describe how to perform that command.

[TF.exe Fast Overview](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/tf-exe-fast-overview/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command from MSDN.
Also, a great tool to compare the status of files, work spaces, and history of change sets or files is [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). This tool is free and very powerful.